# Locust Teardown - Event test stop

Tags: python, events, load-testing, locust, teardown

I am using events in my locust test: @events.test_stop.add_listener and @events.test_start.add_listener

*Problem:* @events.test_stop.add_listener **does not execute DB request.**

*Test structure:*

- Setup
- Test
- Teardown

*Test run parameters:*

- 1 User.
- 1 Spawn rate
- iteration number - 2 (-i)
- locust plugins are installed.
- Python

**Example**: The same code for *@events.test_stop.add_listener* and *@events.test_start.add_listener*

```
@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(environment, **kwargs):
    logging.info('Test start. Trying to query the database.')
    response_db = get_count_port_msg()
    logging.info(f'DB response: {response_db}')


@events.test_stop.add_listener
def on_test_stop(environment, **kwargs):
    logging.info('Test stop. Trying to query the database.')
    response_db = get_count_port_msg()
    logging.info(f'DB response: {response_db}')
```

**Response in command line:**

```
[2023-04-26 14:39:06,054] VDI/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.14.2
[2023-04-26 14:39:17,754] VDI/INFO/root: Test start. Trying to query the database.
[2023-04-26 14:39:17,754] VDI/INFO/root: Execute the request...
[2023-04-26 14:39:17,953] VDI/INFO/root: DB response: 52
[2023-04-26 14:39:17,953] VDI/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 1 users at a rate of 1.00 per second
[2023-04-26 14:39:17,953] VDI/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"LoadTests": 1} (1 total users)
...
[2023-04-26 14:39:23,286] VDI/INFO/root: Iteration limit reached (2), stopping Users at the start of their next task run
[2023-04-26 14:39:23,286] VDI/INFO/root: Last user stopped, quitting runner
[2023-04-26 14:39:23,286] VDI/INFO/root: Test stop. Trying to query the database.
[2023-04-26 14:39:23,286] VDI/INFO/root: Execute the request...
```

Press CTRL+C to exit and view the report.

**Question:** Why don't I have the same on_test_stop response as on_test_start? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that get_count_port_msg() threw an exception? What if you replace that line with time.sleep(), does that also prevent the second line from printing?

Comment: Is there a difference in behaviour if you use a ”regular” time limit, instead of -i?

Comment: Hello, @Cyberwiz
Is it possible that get_count_port_msg() threw an exception? **Answer**: No, impossible

Comment: What if you replace that line with time.sleep(), does that also prevent the second line from printing? **Answer**: Result will be the same.
`[2023-04-27 03:00:22,633] VDI/INFO/root: Test start. Sleep 3 second.
[2023-04-27 03:00:25,635] VDI/INFO/root: Wake up!
[2023-04-27 03:00:30,868] VDI/INFO/root: Test stop. Sleep 3 second.`

Comment: @Cyberwiz Is there a difference in behaviour if you use a ”regular” time limit, instead of -i? Answer:It's work fine.
Config:
headless = true
users = 1
spawn-rate = 1
run-time = 20s 

`[2023-04-27 03:08:21,956] VDI/INFO/root: Test start. Sleep 3 second.
[2023-04-27 03:08:24,972] VDI/INFO/root: Wake up!
[2023-04-27 03:08:41,746] VDI/INFO/locust.main: --run-time limit reached, shutting down
[2023-04-27 03:08:41,746] VDI/INFO/root: Test stop. Sleep 3 second.
[2023-04-27 03:08:44,762] VDI/INFO/root: Wake up!
[2023-04-27 03:08:44,762] VDI/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 0)`

Comment: Conclusions: with iteration (-i) - does not work. With "normal" runs (20 sec) - it works fine. @Cyberwiz any ideas? Thanks for answer!

Comment: This may be a bug in locust. runner.quit should wait for on_stop to finish. Or maybe we can call something other than quit from locust plugins. No real ideas apart from that.

Comment: @Cyberwiz
Can we expect a fix in the new version locust?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have time to investigate more right now, but please go ahead and file a bug with your findings.

Comment: Actually, I may have found something...

Comment: Try now with locust-plugins 3.3.0. I made a fix/workaround here that I think should help: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/commit/d0cb7c2ce54202df64e9cc6eeb9fbe05e3670c79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fix/workaround and released it in locust-plugins 3.3.0.